# jquery/ajax get user input and query a db with out page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have a situations where I need to get the user customer Id ( from a from field) and that query my DB and return his/her zip-code without  page refresh. any help would appreciated.
j.

Comment: You also try to appreciate others answers to your questions

Comment: Write a service on the server end, make an ajax call to this service that would return the desired data in appropriate format (like JSON). The service would accept necessary parameters to complete the request and use it to query the DB.

Comment: hi gotuskar,  can you provide en example of html page and thejquery script . tks

Answer (score 0):

If your form has a submit button, you can give this button a "onclick='queryDB()'" field.

```
<button value="submit" ... onclick="queryDB()" />
```

then your javascript code can include

```
function queryDB(){
   var url = <location of php file>;
   var postData = formField.value(); // gets value from your text input
   jQuery.post( url , postData , function(data){ <...update your page...> });
}
```

This is a basic outline, since I don't have many details about your page. If you are confused, I would recommend checking some tutorials or posting more information.

**edit:**
how about this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="Stackoverflow"/>
   <button onclick="queryDB()">Click Me!</button>
</form>
<div id="postResults33">
</div> 
<script> 
function queryDB(){ 
    var url = 'sendtest.php'; 
    var postData = formField.value(); // gets value from your text input 
    jQuery.post( url , {fieldValue:postData} , function(data){ $("#postResults33").html(data);
}); 
} 
</script>
```

Then your sendtest.php file has to have something that looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST['fieldValue'])){
   userId = $_POST['fieldValue'];
   *get zip code using userId*
   echo zipCode;
}
```

Comment: thanks Susanoh13; here is what i have , but I do not get any result :



<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="queryDB(this); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Stackoverflow"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here"/>
</form>


<div id="postResults33"></div>
<script>
 function queryDB(){
    var url = 'sendtest.php';
    var postData = formField.value(); // gets value from your text input
    jQuery.post( url , postData , function(data){ $("#postResults33").html(data); });
 }
</script>